# How to handle login/logout using @react-oauth/google

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-identity

I am developing a side project that allows a user to login with Google and access/manage their Google Books content.

So far, I have Sign in With Google working via [@react-oauth/google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google). Here is the code:

```
const login = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: (tokenResponse) => {
      console.log("token response", tokenResponse);
      setToken(tokenResponse.access_token);
    },
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books",
  });
```

With this code, I am able to get an OAuth token that allows me to access the user's profile info, as well as make changes to their Google Books bookshelves. After this is where I get confused.

This token is only valid for one hour. Do I need to request a new token every hour if the user remains logged in? Furthermore, how do I "log out" the user? There is a `googleLogout()` function included with [@react-oauth/google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google) but I'm not sure what it does, as the given token is still active after calling this function.